# SQL query to identify max value in an subset of records to be used as boundary condition for Batch Job partitioning

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-processing

I have around 2 million records in the database and I want to us the concept of partitions in one of my batch jobs. In order to do this I need to first identify the boundary records of the partition. Can anyone help out to identify boundry values using SQL query. To illustrate consider i have student records as follows

```
STUDENT_ID    STUDENT_NAME
1             JACK
2             SPARROW
3             JONNY
4             WALKER
5             SKY
6             DANNY
```

Now if i want to create 2 partitions by boundary condition of first partition will be STUDENT_ID between 1 to 3 and STUDENT_ID between 4 to 6. consider similar situation incase student_id is a string or random id. How to identify the bounday condition. Currently I am thinking of first querying all the records in the database and then partitioning them in the java code. But if I have 2 million records this is highly not recommended what should i do in this condition?

Comment: Partitions in mysql are by range, list, hash, or key. I assume you mean partition by range?

Comment: yes partition by range. I want to give a range to each partition and then use pagination to get records between this range in each partition

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit command in mySql as follow:

```
SELECT...
LIMIT y OFFSET x
```